# Trying to play Retropie on my browser

Tags: networking, pi-4, retropie, raspberry-pi-os-buster, uv4l

I flashed the latest retropie image on to my microsd on a raspberry pi 4B using the official raspberry pi imager.

I wanted to do a headless setup since I was on a budget, and it was more appealing to me for retropie to be available to most of my devices over my network, so I followed this guide that promises a headless retropie setup as well as streaming capability in my local network.

https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/play-retropie-in-browser/

I completed the guide, but when I initialized the browser site, it gave me a dialogue that said “invalid video device”.

Digging deeper, I realized that the technology that powered the streaming is called “uv4l” so I sought out forums that had similar errors; however, the issues other users faced involved a camera peripheral, so their solutions weren’t very applicable to my problem. I’m a novice Raspberry Pi user but I am slightly experienced with Linux and the terminal.

There should be screenshots that contain the webpage that retropie should be running on and the error dialog.

https://share.icloud.com/photos/0B12oPmIkneM35mvmLpHdBbIw

https://share.icloud.com/photos/0xPbmF13cqh_A3_zqbOXKBXyQ

Here is the generated /var/log/syslog

https://pastebin.com/8SLfs0HZ

Are there any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but found that the service would work if I plugged the pi into an HDMI monitor while it booted.
To get around this I found help with the issue on the raspberrypi.org forums: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=253312
Simply edit /boot/config.txt to add (or uncomment) this line:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

Once I rebooted I could see from the service status (sudo service uv4l_raspidisp status) that the internal error went away and the video would load in my browser, so long as I uncheck "Use h264 hardware acceleration" under "Options".

I then struggled with (and solved) syncing controllers. In case you have problems as well:
Steps:

1. Boot RetroPie (4) when connected to controller and monitor
2. Plug controller into remote computer
3. Open your rpi’s IP in Chrome browser
4. Under ‘Options’: uncheck ‘Use H264 hardware acceleration’
5. Start stream
6. ON RetroPie Host: use rpi controller to open up "Main Menu -> Configure Input"
7. When prompted to 'HOLD A BUTTON' to config, switch to Remote PC controller
8. Configure your input as you would normally.
9. Unhook your controller from the rpi
10. Done!

Hope that helps!